# How To Upload Image Using Axios React Native?

Tags: react-native, file-upload, axios, react-native-image-picker

I use react-native-image-picker, after successfully taking pictures from the camera I want to upload them to the server. This is my Axios PUT code for uploading images:

```
updateBodyTemperature = async () => {
    try {
      let fistNumber = this.state.textOne.toString()
      let secondNumber = this.state.textTwo.toString()
      let thirdNumber = this.state.textThree.toString()
      let resultOutputNumber = fistNumber + secondNumber + ',' + thirdNumber
      let fd = new FormData()
      fd.append('image', 'file:///' + this.state.markResult)
      let response = await API.put(
        'vendor/tenant-users/body-temperature-data',
        {
          'image': fd,
          'temperature': resultOutputNumber
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + await AsyncStorage.getItem(Config.VENDOR_ACCESS_TOKEN),
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
      alert('Berhasil')
      if (response.data.success){
        this.setState({isFull: true})
      }


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response)
      alert('Gagal')

    }

  }
```

Please help if there is a link or source, please help, thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: What is the result of `this.state.markResult`?

Comment: Yeah bro, My Image doesn't upload. this.state.markerResult is when user capture the image, it will add watermark time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For easy upload image in React Native you can used

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob
```